# percentage of total on two group by and a sum sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage

I have a table that looks like the below:

```
id     Category     Spend
------------------------------
00001    Apple       10
00001    Oranges     4
00001    Apple       21
00001    Oranges     50
00002    Oranges     32
00002    Apple       2
00002    Oranges     31
Etc.
```

And I'm looking to produce a table that would show the below

```
id     Category     Spend_Ratio
------------------------------
00001    Apple       36%
00001    Oranges     64%
00002    Apple       3%
00001    Oranges     97%
```

The logic being to produce a ratio based on category spend grouping by ID.

I've managed to get this far:

```
SELECT id, category, SUM(spend)
FROM table
GROUP BY id, category;
```

Absolutely lost to where to go next..

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
WITH sum_category AS 
(
    SELECT id, category,
        SUM(spend) AS spend
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id, category
)
SELECT id, category,
    ROUND(100 * spend / SUM(spend) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) AS spend_ratio
FROM sum_category
ORDER BY id, category;
```

Try [SqLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8abb0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT id, category, SUM(spend),
       SUM(spend) / SUM(SUM(spend)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as ratio
FROM table
GROUP BY id, category;
```

This produces that value as a number between 0 and 1.  I'm not sure if you really want to format the number as a percentage.